# React-Stormpath on server side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stormpath, express-stormpath

I would like to integrate Stormpath in my React application. Unfortunately React-Stormpath seems to work only on client side and not on server side. I am using the React-Router function `match` to check if the current url is valid (see [React Redux Universal Hot Example](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/server.js#L84)). Unfortunately React Stormpath is only documented for using it`s `Router` component.

Do you know a possibility to implement Stormpath in my React-Redux application also on server side?

I still tried to use the `match` function of React-Stormpath but it is undefined.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not yet supported. I recommend that you watch the GitHub issue for when we implement support for it: https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-react/issues/8

Thanks,

Robin